# Proxy error in IIFE?

Tags: javascript, proxy

My code is this:

```
var cartModule = (function() {
  var cart = [];
  var cart_proxy = new Proxy(cart, handler); *
  var handler = {
    get: function(target, property) {
      ...
    }
  }
})();
```

When I load the page in dev server, there's an error at line `(*)` that says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create proxy with a non-object as target or handler`, but Arrays should work fine...

Does this have something to do with the fact that `cartModule` is an IIFE? I don't know why it would...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says "*as target **or handler***". The array target does indeed work fine, but the `handler` is `undefined` in your code as it has not yet been initialised.

- Use `let` and `const` instead of `var` to get a meaningful exception when trying to use uninitialised variables
- Move the proxy creation after the handler creation:

```
var cartModule = (function() {
  const cart = [];
  const handler = {
    get: function(target, property) {
      ...
    }
  }
  return new Proxy(cart, handler);
})();
```